# Batch script that will insert filenames into files within multiple subfolders

Tags: batch-file, csv

I need help creating a batch script that will add the filename to the first line of every .csv within all subfolders.  The batch file will be in the mainfolder.  The same folder will contain several subfolders, each containing a large amount of .csv files.  I need the files to stay within their respective folders.  My goal is to add this to another working script I have that merges all files within a subfolder into a single .csv.  This will provide a way to navigate through the merged file.  I found some similar posts, but they weren't quite what I was looking for.  This is the closest thing I could find but the delimiter stuff is throwing me off [Batch file to Write Filename to first line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335360/batch-file-to-write-filename-to-first-line)

```
File Structure Example:
C:\MainFolder\batch_script.bat
C:\MainFolder\SubFolder1\csv1.csv
C:\MainFolder\SubFolder1\csv2.csv
C:\MainFolder\SubFolder2\csv3.csv
C:\MainFolder\SubFolder2\csv4.csv
```

File Contents before  running script

```
csv1.csv:
This is the content of csv1.csv

csv2.csv:
This is the content of csv2.csv

csv3.csv:
This is the content of csv3.csv

csv4.csv:
This is the content of csv4.csv
```

File Contents after running script:

```
csv1.csv:
csv1.csv
This is the content of csv1.csv

csv2.csv:
csv2.csv
This is the content of csv2.csv

csv3.csv:
csv3.csv
This is the content of csv3.csv

csv4.csv:
csv4.csv
This is the content of csv4.csv
```

P.S.
I also found this code on another website but I'm not sure how I would make it loop through the different subfolders

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%i IN (`DIR /B`) DO (
ECHO %%i >> %1
TYPE %%i >> %1  
)
```

Comment: Why is there a downvote?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing %-)  It was an insta-downvote

Comment: It would be simpler and faster to add the filenames as the merged file is being created.

Comment: I would certainly be open to that @foxidrive, but I'm not sure how to do that either.  I'm performing the merge through the following command:

`copy C:\MainFolder\Subfolder1\*.csv C:\MainFolder\Subfolder1\all.csv`  
'             '
`copy C:\MainFolder\Subfolder2\*.csv C:\MainFolder\Subfolder2\all.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /r %%a in (*.csv) do (
        set /p "firstLine=" < "%%~fa"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for /f "delims=" %%b in (".!firstLine!") do endlocal & if not "%%~b"==".%%~nxa" (
            (   echo %%~nxa
                type "%%~fa"
            ) > "%%~fa.new" 
            move /y "%%~fa.new" "%%~fa" >nul
        )
    )
```

What it does is generate a new file with the name of the csv as the first line, appends the csv to the new file and moves the new file over the csv. In the process, it tests if the content of the first line is the same as the name of the csv to avoid reinclusion of the filename on each run of the batch file.

**edited** to adapt to comments - As the process will not be run more than once for set of csv files, the full code can be reduced to

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /r %%a in (*.csv) do (
        (   echo %%~nxa
            type "%%~fa"
        ) > "%%~fa.new" 
        move /y "%%~fa.new" "%%~fa" >nul
    )
```

Comment: This sort of worked, however it wrote the file name 10 to 20 times on a lot of the files.  Regarding "avoid reinclusion of the filename on each run of the batch file" I should also note the batch would only run once per set of .csv files/folders.  All csv files/folders will be deleted, and replaced with new .csv files that do not contain their filename.

Comment: @Rob, code update to not test first line. I see no way for the first code to generate more than one line in a file (obviously the second can do it on sucessive runs).

Comment: not sure why that first one generated so many lines on a single run.  Anywho, your updated code worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for /r %%a in (*.csv) do (
copy /y "%%~a" "%temp%\%%~na"
Echo %%~na > "%%~a"
for /f "usebackq" %%b in ("%temp%\%%~na") do Echo %%b >> "%%~a"
del "%temp%\%%~na"
)
```

And that should do what you want it to. I would test it out first if you could.

Comment: Thank you.  I was hoping to avoid creating and deleting new files but  I'll defenitely give this a shot.

Comment: hmmm ran a test and it didn't quite work.  This appears to rewrite each file line by line to a temp file, correct?  This would take a very long time to complete.  Also, it seems to have ruined the content of some of the resulting files.

Answer (score 0):

This should create an `all.csv` in every folder in the tree under the `C:\MainFolder` and add the `filename` before the contents of each `CSV` file.

The filename will contain the full path but that can easily be changed if needed.

```
@echo off
for /d /r "C:\MainFolder\" %%a in (*) do (
   pushd "%%a"
      (for %%b in (*.csv) do (
         echo %%b
         type "%%b"
         )
       )>all.tmp
      ren all.tmp all.csv
   popd
)
pause
```